# update a product attribute with link_to in my admindashboard rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, attributes, link-to

I'm new on Ror...
I would like to Update a Product attribute (:active from False => True) directly from my admin dashboard, using a simple link_to.
When a User add a new product in my app, I (admin) check if the product respects the condition then I publish it, from my admindashboard.
Here is my code:

pages/admindashboard.html.erb

```
Articles on waiting list: <strong><%= @notactives.count %></strong>
<% @notactives.each do |product| %>
<ul>
<li><strong><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %> <%= product.user.pseudo %></strong> (<%= product.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>)
<% if product.active? %>
<p>publié</p>
<% elsif product.status? %>
<p>sold</p>
<% else %>
<span class="label label-success"> <%= link_to "publish the article", publish_product_path %></span>
<% end %>
</li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Pages Controller:

```
  def publish_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
      @product.active = true
      @product.save
    redirect_to :admindashboard
      end
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :brand, :category, :color, :size, :state, :price, :address, :status, :active)
  end
```

routes.rb

```
patch '/publish_product' =>'pages#publish_product'
```

Thk in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the route to accept an id from the params:

```
patch '/publish_product/:id' =>'pages#publish_product'
```

Then in the link_to you use that path plus the id:

```
<% @notactives.each do |product| %>
  ...
  <%= link_to 'publish the article', publish_product_path(product.id) %> 
<% end %>
```

And in the controller you "flips" the attribute based on the current value, like:

```
def publish_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.active = !@product.active
  redirect_to :admindashboard if @product.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, but that still doesn't work... I have the following error: NoMethodError in Pages#admindashboard          undefined method `publish_product_path'                              <span class="label label-success">  <%= link_to 'publish the article', publish_product_path(product.id) %>
</span>

Comment: That's a route name error, could you try by updating the route and giving it an alias? `patch '/publish_product/:id' =>'pages#publish_product', as: :publish_product`

Comment: Now I have a new error: Routing error    No route matches [GET] "/publish_product/16"

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, note that link_to by default creates a GET request, so you must specify the HTTP verb to be used will be PATCH, use the method option, like `<%= link_to 'publish the article', publish_product_path(product.id), method: :patch %>`.

Comment: Great you're right. That works! Thks @Sebastian Palma